# .Net Route Action Parameter coming back null despite being in url

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, routes

UPDATE: It works fine is I add another parameter. I have no idea why.

Not sure what I am doing wrong, this route looks the same as the other routes, I've looked at all the other stackoverflow posts on the subject and everything looks up to snuff. Maybe someone can see something I can't?

`Error: action parameter can't be null`

The url: `http://localhost:1319/EntryHistory/Entry/B2AAAA4A-B174-4C28-924F-A3B2027DD745`

EntryHistoryController.cs:

```
  public class EntryHistoryController : Controller
    {
        
        public ActionResult Entry(string entryId)
        {
            Guid parsedEntryId = Guid.Parse(entryId);
            var history = new EntryHistoryService().BuildEntryHistoryViewModel(parsedEntryId);
            return View(history);
        }
    }
```

RouteConfig.cs

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
           ...
            EntryHistoryRoutes(routes);
          ...
}
 private static void EntryHistoryRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {

            routes.MapRoute(
                "revisionhistory",
                "entryhistory/entry/{entryId}",
                new
                {
                    controller = "entryhistory",
                    action = "entry",
                    entryId = UrlParameter.Optional
                }
            );



         }
```

Comment: have you tried renaming your action method to index ?

Comment: Just tried it and didn't work

Comment: And why is `entryId` marked as an optional parameter? It looks to me like it's needed.

Comment: Moreover, why provide defaults for controller and action when the route is clearly very specific?

Answer (score 0):

add attribute routing

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
       ...... your routes

       //convention-based routes
       routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

and action

```
[Route("~/entryhistory/entry/{entryId}")]
public ActionResult Entry(string entryId)
```